# Load custom library while using CDN

Tags: http-status-code-404, cdn, sapui5

I have an app that uses a custom application-specific library (sap.ui.foo) which contains custom controls, views and controllers.

My deployment strategy is serving my custom library from the same server/port that is serving the index.html file.

I would also like to use SAP's CDN to load the OpenUI5 libraries (sap.m, etc).

I am using the Grunt/node tools that come with [OpenUI5's GitHub repository](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/).

When I load my application all locally (no CDN) it works perfectly, but is very slow (such a huge download payload I suppose) so I'm trying to use the CDN in hopes of improving startup performance.

My `index.html` looks like this: (edited after @codeworrior's answer):

```
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
         src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
         data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
         data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.layout, sap.m, sap.ui.foo"
         data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
         data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
             "ns":"./",
             "sap.ui.foo": "./sap/ui/foo/"
         }'
    >
```

Here is my directory structure (which to my knowledge is "standard"):

```
src
├── foo
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── webapp
│               ├── index.html # start point
│               ├── resources
│               ├── test-resources
│               └── WEB-INF
├── sap.m
├── sap.ui.commons
...other sap libs...
└── sap.ui.foo
    └── src
        └── sap
            └── ui
                └── foo
                    └── # my controls...
```

and after a `grunt build:production` my "target" directory looks like this:

```
target
├── openui5-sap.m
├── openui5-sap.ui.commons
├── openui5-sap.ui.core
├── openui5-sap.ui.demokit
├── ...other sap libs...
├── openui5-sap.ui.foo
    └── resources
        └── sap
            └── ui
                └── foo
                    ├── Bootstrap.js
                    ├── controllers
                    ├── controls
                    ├── data
                    ├── font
                    ├── img
                    ├── js
                    ├── library.js
                    ├── library-preload.json
                    ├── models
                    ├── tasks
                    ├── themes
                    ├── util.js
                    ├── views
                    └── wrappers
```

But, after I do a `grunt serve:target` and hit the url http://localhost:8989/foo/, in Chrome's dev-tools I get:

```
failed to preload 'sap.ui.foo.library-preload': Not Found -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/foo/library.js' from ./sap/ui/foo/library.js: 404 - Not Found
```

The network tab shows me that the CDN files are being served just fine, but the files that I'm trying to serve locally (such as my custom lib's library.js and library-preload.json) are 404's.

Any advice on how to get my library to load?

Comment: wouldn't adding another script tag in your index, with the `src` being the location of where the custom library is stored, work?

Comment: @Breakpoint how can I do that for a lib though (not just a file)?

Answer (score 1):

If your library is stored in the usual way (reflecting the full qualified names in the folder structure), then it should be sufficient to define a corresponding entry in your data-sap-ui-resourceroots attribute:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
 src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
 data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
 data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.layout, sap.m, my.uilib"
 data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
 data-sap-ui-resourceroots="{
   ns:'./',
   'my.uilib': './my/uilib/'
 }">
</script>
```

If the structure is different, just adapt the path in the configuration. resourceRoots are configured early, so you could even specify your lib in the data-sap-ui-libs attribute.

But maybe you tried that already and it didn't work. Then the problem might have been with the spelling of the option. It's 'resourceroots', not 'resource-roots'.

Comment: Thanks @codeworrior, this got me a bit closer I believe. I'm still getting 404's when trying to local my local content (the CDN content is loading just fine). I updated my question with more details, hopefully that makes it easier to diagnose the issue.